# Printing JSP form data on another JSP page

Tags: java, jsp

I have a jsp form that takes different inputs from user.
How can I print the submitted data on another jsp page?

Comment: Two stage: 1. accept data (and store somewhere: session, database, url, cache) 2. print it.

Comment: what is REAL usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first JSP page:

```
<form method="post" action="otherPage.jsp">
   <input type="text" name="firstName">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

then on the `otherPage.jsp` you can get the value of the input:

```
<%
    String name = request.getParameter("firstName");
    out.println("Firstname: " + name);
%>
```

..although using scriptlets is normally discouraged.

If you want to use e.g. Spring MVC you post the form to a `Controller` which handles the request and there you can pass the parameters forward.

Comment: ..I have used the same solution..Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @Marium ok, so you already know how to do it? why are you asking?

Comment: I'm asking if there is any other way to do the same

Comment: @Marium then you should have written that in your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Alternatively you can use a web framework, like Spring MVC, J2EE, or anything else.. there are Many!!

Comment: Like putting the form data into an object and then printing the data from that object

Comment: @Marium look [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) or [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm)

Comment: "..although using scriptlets is normally discouraged." Then why post answer which uses technology that went out of fashion in the early 2000s.

Comment: @AlanHay because he didn't mention anything else than JSP pages.

Comment: An answer using JSTL tags or JSP EL to output the data would be more relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The use of scriptlets in JSP is strongly discouraged:

[How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files?rq=1)

You can achieve the same using JSP Expression Language (JSP EL):

```
<p>First name was ${param.firstName}</p>
```